# Query taking more than one minute to execute

Tags: t-sql

Executing my current query takes 1:16 minutes. That is way too long. Here is how my query looks like atm:

```
SELECT

    [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Id,

    [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Title,

    [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created,

    [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].StartProgress,

    [dbo].[worktime]([plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created, GetDate()) AS OpenstaandeTijdInUren,

    [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].firstresponse,

    DATEDIFF(HOUR, [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created, [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].FirstResponse) AS ReactietijdInUren,

    [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Status,

    [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Priority,

         DATEDIFF (MINUTE, [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created, [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].EndProgress) as OplostijdTicketInUren



FROM

    [plugin.tickets].[Ticket]

WHERE

    [dbo].[worktime](

        [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created, GetDate()

    ) >= 1

    AND (

        [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].status <= 2

    )

ORDER BY

    [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].id
```

In the query there is a function I use which I made. The function calculates the difference in hours between two dates. For calculating the time excluding holidays I have made a table which contains the holidays for oncoming 10 years. Most likely thats why it is taking so long for the query to execute, because for every row it checks of the date contains same date as the holiday table. But I am not sure what the solution for this problem is?

Here is my function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkTime]

(

    @StartDate DATETIME,

    @FinishDate DATETIME

)

RETURNS BIGINT

AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @Temp BIGINT

    SET @Temp=0



       --DECLARE @hdays Table (values) date

       --insert into @hdays

       --select [Datum_Feestdag]  --= (Datum_feestdag)

       --from [dbo].[Feestdagen] 



    DECLARE @FirstDay DATE

    SET @FirstDay = CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate, 112)



    DECLARE @LastDay DATE

    SET @LastDay = CONVERT(DATE, @FinishDate, 112)



    DECLARE @StartTime TIME

    SET @StartTime = CONVERT(TIME, @StartDate)



    DECLARE @FinishTime TIME

    SET @FinishTime = CONVERT(TIME, @FinishDate)



    DECLARE @WorkStart TIME

    SET @WorkStart = '08:00'



    DECLARE @WorkFinish TIME

    SET @WorkFinish = '18:00'



    DECLARE @DailyWorkTime BIGINT

    SET @DailyWorkTime = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @WorkStart, @WorkFinish)



    IF (@StartTime<@WorkStart)

    BEGIN

        SET @StartTime = @WorkStart

    END

    IF (@FinishTime>@WorkFinish)

    BEGIN

        SET @FinishTime=@WorkFinish

    END

    IF (@FinishTime<@WorkStart)

    BEGIN

        SET @FinishTime=@WorkStart

    END

    IF (@StartTime>@WorkFinish)

    BEGIN

        SET @StartTime = @WorkFinish

    END

    DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE

    SET @CurrentDate = @FirstDay

    DECLARE @LastDate DATE

    SET @LastDate = @LastDay





    WHILE(@CurrentDate<=@LastDate)

    BEGIN     

        IF

             (DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=1 AND DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=7)

             and @CurrentDate not in (select Datum_feestdag from Feestdagen)

        --@CurrentDate not in (@hdays)

             BEGIN

            IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)

            BEGIN

                SET @Temp = @Temp + @DailyWorkTime

            END

            --IF it starts at startdate and it finishes not this date find diff between work finish and start as hours

            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)

            BEGIN

                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(HOUR, @StartTime, @WorkFinish)

            END



            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)

            BEGIN

                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(HOUR, @WorkStart, @FinishTime)

            END

            --IF it starts and finishes in the same date

            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)

            BEGIN

                SET @Temp = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @StartTime, @FinishTime)

            END

        END

        SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate)

    END



    -- Return the result of the function

    IF @Temp<0

    BEGIN

        SET @Temp=0

    END

    RETURN @Temp

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is taking longer than it should most likely because you are calculating your values row by row in a `while` loop.  This is fundamentally *not* how SQL databases are supposed to be used.

Try to solve your problem by combining and comparing sets of data, rather than iterating over each value in your table.  A starting point for you to develop your own solution would be something like this:

```
declare @t table(id int,StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime);
insert into @t values
 (1,'2019/01/01 00:00:00','2019/01/02 15:00:00')
,(2,'2019/01/02 04:00:00','2019/01/03 15:00:00')
,(3,'2019/01/02 08:30:00','2019/01/02 15:00:00')
,(4,'2019/01/04 13:45:00','2019/01/07 15:30:00')
,(5,'2019/01/07 22:00:00','2019/02/03 15:00:00');

declare @EarliestStart datetime;
declare @LatestEnd datetime;

select @EarliestStart = min(StartDate)
      ,@LatestEnd = max(EndDate)
from @t;

declare @WorkStart time = '08:00';
declare @WorkEnd time = '18:00';


with n(n) as (select t from(values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t(t))    -- Crete a tally table of numbers, by taking the ROW_NUMBER of 10 rows CROSS JOINed multiple times.  In this case 6 times for 10*10*10*10*10*10 = 1,000,000 potential rows
    ,m(m) as (select top(datediff(minute,@EarliestStart,@LatestEnd)+1) dateadd(minute,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,@EarliestStart) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4,n n5,n n6)  -- and add that number as minutes to the minumum StartTime up to the maximum EndTime for a list of all potentially worked minutes
    ,w(w) as (select m from m where cast(m as time) >= @WorkStart and cast(m as time) < @WorkEnd)   -- then filter this list of minutes to just those that can be worked
select t.id
        ,t.StartDate
        ,t.EndDate
        ,count(w.w)/60. as WorkingHours
        ,count(w.w) as WorkingMinutes
from @t as t
    join w
        on t.StartDate <= w.w       -- JOIN onto the list of dates to get a row for each minute actually worked between each StartDate and EndDate, that can be COUNTed for total working time
            and t.EndDate > w.w
group by t.id
        ,t.StartDate
        ,t.EndDate
order by t.id
        ,t.StartDate
        ,t.EndDate;
```

## Output

```
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------------+
| id |        StartDate        |         EndDate         | WorkingHours | WorkingMinutes |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------------+
|  1 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-01-02 15:00:00.000 |    17.000000 |           1020 |
|  2 | 2019-01-02 04:00:00.000 | 2019-01-03 15:00:00.000 |    17.000000 |           1020 |
|  3 | 2019-01-02 08:30:00.000 | 2019-01-02 15:00:00.000 |     6.500000 |            390 |
|  4 | 2019-01-04 13:45:00.000 | 2019-01-07 15:30:00.000 |    31.750000 |           1905 |
|  5 | 2019-01-07 22:00:00.000 | 2019-02-03 15:00:00.000 |   267.000000 |          16020 |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really dont want to make another function orso because I am not a expert in SQL and it already took me a long time to be able to make the current function I am using work. I see that u declare the variable '@t' and then insert value into it. In my function I have commented out a variable called '@hdays'. How can I insert value of an existing column into '@hdays'. Maybe that way my query wil improve dont you think? @iamdave

Comment: @Shabbo  The `@t` in the above script is a table variable.  I have used it entirely as a store for test data.  You would replace this with `[plugin.tickets].[Ticket]` table.  There is also no need for *any* functions if you only need the one query.  What I have provided above is not a function, nor does it use any user defined functions.

Comment: I am using the function because I need to get the calculated time of 2 dates excluding weekends and holidays. Also in between the working hours as you can see in my function that I posted.

Comment: Yes, and you can do that with my script.  You just need to exclude the time periods in the `w` part of the `common table expression`.  As I say, you do not need a function at all to get the working hours.